# What's the name of this $\sigma$-algebra (iterated probabilites)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

Let $(\Omega_0,\Sigma_0)$ be a $\sigma$-algebra and $\Omega_1$ the set of probability measures $P$ on $(\Omega_0,\Sigma_0)$.  Let $\Sigma_1$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega_1$ which contains the sets $\{P:P(E)\le p\}$ for $E\in\Sigma_0$, $p\in[0,1)$.

Does this construction have a name or are there any articles exploring it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this often and have even worked with it, without knowing any specific name. It is easy to show that a random variable with values in $\Omega_1$ is essentially a transition probability. That is, if $(X,\mathcal{X})$ is a measurable space and $f:X\to\Omega_1$ a function, then $f$ is $\mathcal{X}/\Sigma_1$-measurable if and only if the function $\kappa:X\times\Sigma_1\to[0,1]$ given by $\kappa(x,B)=f(x)(B)$ is a transition probability. There exists a lot of work on transition probabilities.

In the case that $\Omega_0$ is a separable metrizable space and $\Sigma_0$ is its Borel $\sigma$-algebra,  $\Sigma_1$ is simply the Borel $\sigma$-algebra corresponding to the topology of weak convergence on measures. For a proof, see Proposition 7.25 in Bertsekas and Shreve 1978, *Stochastic optimal control: The discrete time case*.